# Is it possible to support non-english comments while using mercurial with hgsubversion?

Tags: svn, mercurial

I'm testing mercurial now with hgsubversion extension. All works fine except subversion comments: non-latin characters are shown as "?" in HGWorkbench and it crashes with python encoding error while working with changesets that has non-latin characters in comments. Is it possible to somehow fix such behavior or mercurial-subversion bridge is not intended to be used with non-English languages?

**Update 12 April 2012**

I have checked OS version - the bug only displays itself on Windows. On Ubuntu all works fine and non-latin comments are displayed correctly. Also it seems this is HGWorkbench application problem: i copied repository checked out in Ubuntu that is displayed correctly in Ubuntu into Windows computer and i see "?" instead of non-latin characters here.

Comment: A good question, but probably better asked through hgsubversion project support channels.

Comment: @Chris I will surely ask it via hgsubversion support channels if stackoverflow fails. Stackoverflow is simply faster compared to mailing list, and task seems to me very common, so it's a high chance that someone already stumbled into it and has a working solution :).

Comment: I have tested it on Windows 7 64-bit English. I have tried it on Ubuntu, but clone speed was like 1 commit per second and it crashed after ~ 2 days of clone process due to bug in Mercurial code that incorrectly handles network problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, it seems that TortoiseHG is not intended to be used on Windows after all. The workaround for encoding problem is to set environment variable named "HGENCODING" with "UTF-8" value.